# Is there an automatic way to generate thebibliography}{99}

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I want to submit my manuscript to a journal that requests specific formatting for the references list. They required the formating as follows:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{journal-1} A.~P.~Raposo, H.~J.~Weber, D.~E.~Alvarez--Castillo, M.~Kirchbach, 
Cent. Eur. J. Phys. 5, 253 (2007)

\end{thebibliography}
```

I have used this format to generate the reference list of my paper:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\bibliography{mybib2}
```

I have more than 30 references, and it is hard to use the required references manually.

My question is, is there a way to convert my bibliography to the one requested by the journal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run BibTeX, the `.bbl` file (which is loaded by your `\bibliography` command) contains the commands for setting the `thebibliography` environment. Assuming you have an appropriate bibliography style (or one close enough that your references can easily be modified to fit the specifications of the journal), you can just take the output from BibTeX and paste it into your document in place of the `\bibliography` command.